# Как запустить файл Node.JS в Docker?

Tags: node.js, docker

На сервере предыдущий разработчик разместил нодовский файл в этой папке:

`../docker/local/php/code/simple.js`

С помощью какой команды мне можно его вызвать в Docker?

Comment: а `Dockerfile` или `docker-compose.yml` там есть где-нибудь рядом?

Answer (score 1):

### Просто

перейти в директорию с файлом и выполнить

```
docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):/tmp node:carbon node /tmp/simple.js
```

### Сложно (для примера, просто размышления)

> Это просто пример одного из вариантов, можно использовать как основу для размышлений. Тут много слов, но может это поможет кому-то в качестве отправной точки. Описать все возможные варианты, конечно, не представляется возможным. Это зависит от каждого конкретного приложения.

Нужно понять, что задумывал разработчик (а также посмотреть "поблизости" файлы `Dockerfile` или `docker-compose.yml`):

- собирать образ?
- использовать `docker-compose` или `docker stack`?
- есть ли у скрипта зависимости?

Проверить, что docker (docker-compose) установлен

```
docker info
docker-compose version
```

А также посмотреть доступные образы, возможно (если вы выполняете работы на сервере) уже есть и образы и контейнеры

```
# список образов
docker image list 
# работающие контейнеры
docker ps  
# все контейнеры
docker ps -a
```

Перейти в директорию файла (для удобства)

```
cd <путь на сервере>/docker/local/php/code/simple.js
```

посмотреть в интерактивном режиме, чтобы понять "что присходит"

```
docker run -it --rm \
    -v $(pwd):/tmp \
    node:carbon \
    node tmp/simple.js
```

По итогам аналитики, если нужно, то создать `Dockerfile` и `docker-compose.yml`

Пример файла Dockerfile

```
FROM node:carbon

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# если у файла есть зависимости,
# то логика сборки должна включать 
# их установку. Файлы можно копировать
# в образ или монтировать, это зависит от
# конкретного приложения.
# COPY . .
# RUN npm i    

CMD ["node","simple.js"]
```

Сборка образа

```
docker build -t simplejs .
```

Пример docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
# ports 3000 - только для примера!
services:
  app:
    image: simplejs
    # если не устанавливали зависимости,
    # то можем просто примонтировать текущую директорию,
    # чтобы иметь возможность редактировать файл
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
    # зависит от того что делает скрипт,
    # возможно это express или что-то подобное,
    # а может и нет... 
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

И например запуск в фоновом режиме

```
docker-compose up -d
```